# What is a semi-hollow organ?

Tags: emergency, internal-organs

This question was taken from an NREMT (EMT certification) test I took and will have to re-take, so the context is emergency medicine/first response. It asked me to list some semi-hollow organs. This was never covered in my class, it's not in my textbook, and I can't find a single result for "semi-hollow organs" on Google. What could they be asking about?

Comment: Did you ask your instructors?

Comment: Can you give the exact text of the question or at least a good approximation?

Comment: I'm not a medical expert, but could organs such as the gall bladder, and the adrenal glands be considered semi hollow, as the contain ducts, but aren't composed of ducts?